# All components being bundled

Tags: babeljs, antd, webpack-4

I just upgraded to webpack 4 and babel 7, and have noticed my bundle has increased in size considerably.

using bundle analyzer, I can see antd and it's dependents are about 1MB of my 1.7mb bundle.[image]

When bundling in development mode I can see all of the antd components are being included, even though my app currently has a single button imported

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
....
```

How can I load only what I need? Here are my relevant configs

```
//webpack.config
{
  devtool: false,
  mode: 'production',
  entry: [
    '@babel/polyfill',
    'antd/dist/antd.css',
    './js/router',
    './css/test.less',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './plugins/js'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
....
```

And:

```
//babelrc
{
  "presets": [
      ['@babel/preset-env', { 
        modules: false, 
        useBuiltIns: 'entry', 
        targets: { 
          chrome:"58", ie: "11" 
        } 
      }],
      '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  "plugins": [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
      ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you enable import on demand? https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand

Comment: @A.com I'v configured it as far as I'm away. It's in my babelrc in the op. I also tried changing it to be like an example in that page:
`["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "ant"],`
But no change. I also don't get that console message warning about using the full library.

Answer (score 0):

In development mode, by default the option `sideEffects:true` disables tree shaking. Test in production to see if this works. To enable in development:
- use imports exports
- @babel/preset-env is set to `modules: false`.
- Add `sideEffects:false` in pkg.json. Alternatively, the array accepts relative, absolute, and glob patterns to the relevant files.

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion

Comment: I added `sideEffects:true` to my package.json and rebuilding and there has been no noticeable change. I am running this in production mode, and all of the library modules are still in the final bundle.

Comment: Can you test for a given module. I don't think this behavior is across the board. So if you're importing lodash and following the rules above, do you see your lodash bundles smaller?

Comment: So I installed lodash and imported as `import _ from 'lodash'` and `import { get } from 'lodash'`.
The bundle size was the same between both, there didn't seem to be any difference.